# How to use .share() with Subject [Swift Combine]

Tags: swift, combine

If I have a Subject and subscribe it from many places like below, should I use .share()? Or .share() does nothing in this case?

```
let sampleSubject = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("")
sampleSubject.sink { print($0) }
sampleSubject.sink { print($0) }
sampleSubject.sink { print($0) }
sampleSubject.sink { print($0) }
```

```
let sharedSampleSubject = sampleSubject.share()
sharedSampleSubject.sink { print($0) }
sharedSampleSubject.sink { print($0) }
sharedSampleSubject.sink { print($0) }
sharedSampleSubject.sink { print($0) }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most publishers are `struct`s - value-types - so when you subscribe to them, it actually creates a copy of the pipeline.

`.share()` gives them reference semantics. But, subjects like `PassthroughSubject` and `CurrentValueSubject` are already classes, so in this case, it doesn't do anything.

But, imagine we had a pipeline that publishes a value alongside a counter as a tuple. This can be done with `.scan` operator:

```
let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
let publisher = subject.scan((0, ""), { ($0.0 + 1, $1) })
```

If you subscribe to it and send some values, like this:

```
let c1 = publisher.sink { print("c1:", $0) }
subject.send("a")
subject.send("b")
```

The output would be:

```
c1: (1, "a")
c1: (2, "b")
```

But, what would happen to the counter if you were to subscribe to it again?

```
let c2 = publisher.sink { print("c2:", $0) }
subject.send("c")
```

Since we didn't use `.share`, the output would be:

```
c1: (3, "c")
c2: (1, "c")
```

The second subscriber started counting from 1 again, since it got a new copy of `Scan` with an initial value of 0.

With `.share`, it would have been:

```
c1: (3, "c")
c2: (3, "c")
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! I got it.